# Can you resize a loaded image and save it with its new size? AS3

Tags: android, ios, performance, actionscript-3

Im developing an App and the assets used are for the highest resolution screens available so smaller devices have a hard time rendering such big images besides it uses alot of unnecesary memory. So what i want to do is: When you start the App for the first time it will go through all assets resizing them to the size that will always be used on that device so the rendering time will be much shorter and memory use will be lower.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you'd better pack assets of other common sizes with the app, and use appropriate size at install time, not at run time. If there are too many of them, make your app download assets from elsewhere with the same outcome. Your approach is IIRC possible, but I don't have knowledge on how to store assets on IOS, there might be limited storage capabilities involved. You can try using one `SharedObject` to store re-encoded assets, and load them if they are available.

Comment: Mmm, forgot to mention that my App is a game so assets are quite heavy, 33 MB, so packing the other sizes will make it even larger! Altough i have heard that the play store let's you upload different apks, with different sized assets, and the play store distributes them to the corresponding device, but im not sure about the App store including that feature. I think the SharedObject's max size is 100KB, that is far too little to store what i need to store. About loading assets from elsewhere, from where do you mean? I have little knowledge on that.

Comment: And if i were to load assets from elsewhere, how would i store the assets loaded? I don't wanna load the same assets each time i have to start the game...

Comment: Yes it's possible I do that all the time either on Ios or Android. Resizing and saving on disk is possible but I prefer to do that dynamically and keep those assets in memory. Also I do not resize all at start but on a per need basis, if the resized asset is available I use it, if it's not I create it and store it.

Comment: It is good to know that you can do that but the question is how, please answer as an answer not as a comment so i can up vote you and mark you as the correct answer

Comment: Mmmm i think i got it, its with a matrix, thanks

Comment: BotMaster I tried your solution and it didnt work, it is actually taking longer now. How exactly do you do this? I would really appreciate an answer and not a comment.